# Formatting multinomial regression table using gtsummary; how to get rid of "NA" row that appears before glance_table?

Tags: r, format, regression, gtsummary, glance

I am creating a table that summarized my multinomial regression function.

```
HappyData$HappyScale <- relevel(HappyData$HappyScale, ref = "Pretty Happy")

H1 <- multinom(HappyScale ~ Black + Hispanic + Female, data = HappyData)
```

Happy Scale --> 3 level ordered variable (not using ordinal regression as proportional odds assumption failed). "Not Very Happy", "Pretty Happy", and "Very Happy". "Pretty Happy" is the reference category for this regression.
Black, Female, and Hispanic --> 0 or 1 dummy variables

When I add a glance table that includes N and AIC:

```
tbl1 <- tbl_regression(H1, exponentiate = TRUE)%>%
  add_significance_stars(
        hide_se = FALSE,
        hide_ci = FALSE) %>%
  bold_labels() %>%
  italicize_levels()%>%
  add_glance_table(c(nobs, AIC))

tbl1
```

It produces this:
[image]

How do I get rid of the row that only has "NA" in it (right above No.Obs)? Can I change the "NA" to something else if I can't delete the row?

Also, can I add a Pseudo R2 value to the glance table?

Comment: Please update your post with a minimal reproducible example, aka a reprex. https://reprex.tidyverse.org/

Comment: Please also include code for calculating the pseudo R2

Comment: I have provided a reproducible code for this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75482463/multinomial-regression-table-using-gtsummary-how-to-get-rid-of-na-row).